# Is there a free solution to count the number of context roots in an apache file?

Tags: log-files

I have an apache log file.  I need to report how many rows (request) are from a specific context root.  The apache logs already start with a slash and context root is to the second slash.

Example Apache Log:

```
11.222.33.44 - - [14/Feb/2013:00:27:33 -0600] "GET /lifecontent/monitor?test=siteseer&format=siteseer HTTP/1.1" 200 275 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 4.01; Windows NT)" "SSL=on"
111.22.333.44 - - [14/Feb/2013:00:29:29 -0600] "GET /lc/Brokerage%20Manager/IDG%20Licensing%20and%20Appointment%20Process/IDG%20Franchise%20Reference%20Manual HTTP/1.1" 302 - "-" "(Windows NT)" "SSL=-"
```

The two context roots would be **"/lifecontent/"** and **"/lc"**

Not sure what tool would be best?  I am comfortable with GUI or batch solution.

I mostly am just trying to figure out what percentage each context root is being used within an apache files. (Ideally it could search through multiple files at once, but not a requirement.)

Comment: any kind of log analyzer that can parse apache log files would suffice. You might have to prep your logs with sed if the analyzer you turn up doesn't aggregate results according to your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a simple shell script:

```
cut -d/ -f4 access.log | sort | uniq -c | sort -g
```

The `cut` command extracts the 5th /-delimited field (i.e. the "context root"), `sort | uniq -c` then counts the number of occurrences of each, and `sort -g` orders them by number of occurrences.

Running this on my webserver gives:

```
   5477 misc
  11130 bzr
  32181 raspbian
  35912 files
  43020 sites
```

Answer (score 0):

I accepted mgorven solution because it sent me in the right direction for a final working solution.  Afetr using his solution, sometimes there are query string values and sometimes the context root does not have have an ending slash. So "/lc/" and "/lc" and "/lc?x=y" get counted as "lc".  So I ending up using this solution:

```
cut -d" " -f7 access.log | cut -d? -f1 | cut -d/ -f2 | sort | uniq -c | sort -g
```

This will show individual files that got accessed and an empty line if just "/" was accessed.

Also I did this on windows using UnxUtils.zip:  http://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils.  All I needed to extract was cut, sort, uniq.

Thank you mgorven!!